# How to design a relational database schema for music recordings?

Tags: database-design, normalization, constraint

I would like to design a simple *relational database schema* for music recordings and normalize it to the ultimate normal form with respect to the projection and join relational operators, which is projection–join normal form, denoted PJ/NF ([Fagin 1979](https://doi.org/10.1145/582095.582120)). I only credit primary artists for simplicity, excluding composers, performers, engineers, and producers. At some dates, some labels publish some releases of some types (single, extended play, or album) credited to some artists and featuring as tracks some recordings. Hereafter is my design attempt based on those requirements.

First, I define a database schema.

1. I choose seven *attributes*: {date, label, release, type, artist, track, recording}.
2. I choose two basic *constraints*:

- {date, label, release, type} ↠ {artist} (C<sub>1</sub>);
- {date, label, release, type, track} → {recording} (C<sub>2</sub>),

where *X* → *Y* denotes a functional dependency ([Codd 1974](https://exhibits.stanford.edu/feigenbaum/catalog/ys277xx1104)) and *X* ↠ *Y* denotes a multivalued dependency ([Fagin 1977](https://doi.org/10.1145/320557.320571)).

I get a database schema *R*(date, label, release, type, artist, track, recording).

**Are those constraints correct?**

Then, I start the database normalization to PJ/NF:

1. *R*(date, label, release, type, artist, track, recording) is not in PJ/NF because C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub> are not implied by the set of key dependencies {KEY({date, label, release, type, artist, track, recording})}.
2. I decompose *R*(date, label, release, type, artist, track, recording) into *R*<sub>1</sub>(date, label, release, type, artist) and *R*<sub>2</sub>(date, label, release, type, track, recording) on the basis of C<sub>1</sub>.
3. *R*<sub>1</sub>(date, label, release, type, artist) is in PJ/NF because ∅ implies C<sub>1</sub> (i.e. C<sub>1</sub> is a trivial dependency) so the set of key dependencies {KEY({date, label, release, type, artist})} implies C<sub>1</sub>.
4. *R*<sub>2</sub>(date, label, release, type, track, recording) is in PJ/NF because C<sub>2</sub> implies the key dependency KEY({date, label, release, type, track}) which implies C<sub>2</sub> so the set of key dependencies {KEY({date, label, release, type, track}), KEY({date, label, release, type, track, recording})} implies C<sub>2</sub>.

I get a normalized database schema in PJ/NF:

- *R*<sub>1</sub>(date, label, release, type, artist);
- *R*<sub>2</sub>(date, label, release, type, track, recording).

**Is that normalization correct?**

Finally, I instantiate the normalized database schema to get an example database:

| date | label | release | type | artist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1968-08-26 | Apple | Hey Jude | single | The Beatles |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | Michael Jackson |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | Elton John |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | Tim Rice |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | Hans Zimmer |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | Madonna |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | Madonna |

| date | label | release | type | track | recording |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1968-08-26 | Apple | Hey Jude | single | 1 | Hey Jude |
| 1968-08-26 | Apple | Hey Jude | single | 2 | Revolution |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 1 | Wanna Be Startin’ Somethin’ |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 2 | Baby Be Mine |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 3 | The Girl Is Mine (with Paul McCartney) |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 4 | Thriller |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 5 | Beat It |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 6 | Billie Jean |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 7 | Human Nature |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 8 | P.Y.T. (Pretty Young Thing) |
| 1982-11-30 | Epic | Thriller | album | 9 | The Lady in My Life |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 1 | Circle of Life |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 2 | I Just Can’t Wait to Be King |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 3 | Be Prepared |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 4 | Hakuna Matata |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 5 | Can You Feel the Love Tonight |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 6 | This Land (score) |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 7 | …To Die For (score) |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 8 | Under the Stars (score) |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 9 | King of Pride Rock (score) |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 10 | Circle of Life |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 11 | I Just Can’t Wait to Be King |
| 1994-05-31 | Walt Disney | The Lion King: Original Motion Picture Soundtrack | album | 12 | Can You Feel the Love Tonight (end title) |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 1 | Survival |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 2 | Secret |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 3 | I’d Rather Be Your Lover (featuring Meshell Ndegeocello) |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 4 | Don’t Stop |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 5 | Inside of Me |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 6 | Human Nature |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 7 | Forbidden Love |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 8 | Love Tried to Welcome Me |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 9 | Sanctuary |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 10 | Bedtime Story |
| 1994-10-25 | Maverick | Bedtime Stories | album | 11 | Take a Bow |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 1 | Survival |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 2 | Secret |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 3 | I’d Rather Be Your Lover (featuring Meshell Ndegeocello) |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 4 | Don’t Stop |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 5 | Inside of Me |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 6 | Human Nature |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 7 | Forbidden Love |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 8 | Love Tried to Welcome Me |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 9 | Sanctuary |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 10 | Bedtime Story |
| 1994-10-25 | Sire | Bedtime Stories | album | 11 | Take a Bow |